# Jeffreys' priors as coefficients of a linear estimator

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

I asked the following question in a forum more suitable for statistics, but I didn't get any answer; I hope, someone could shed light on my question:

I have three random variables, $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$, which they are distributed normally. If we consider an estimator which reads as:
$$\hat{\theta} = a_1 X_1 + a_2 X_2 +a_3X_3,$$
with the constraint: $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 1$, we know that for $a_i \propto 1/\sigma_i^2$, where $\sigma_i$'s are the standard deviations of $X_i$'s, the estimator has the smallest variance (for proof, see Theorem 3.2., [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.04055.pdf)).

Now, my question is: What is the significance of choosing the coefficients in the above sum as Jeffreys' priors, that is, $a_i \propto 1 / \sigma_i$?

Does $a_i \propto 1 / \sigma_i$ result, for example, in the largest acceptable variance of the estimator? Perhaps, one can say, in the case of complete ignorance, i.e., uninformative priors, the variance of $\hat{\theta}$ should be the largest acceptable variance. Is this argument valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients $a_i$ of the random variables $X_i$ are not any prior probabilities at all -- because prior probabilities are coefficients, not of random variables, but of probability distributions.

The choice $a_i\propto 1/\sigma_i$ in your setting  equalizes the variances of the random variables $a_iX_i$, and that is all it does.

---

Even though priors have actually nothing to do with your question, for criticisms of Jeffreys' "noninformative" priors one may want to see e.g. [Section 4.1](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-24/issue-2/Harold-Jeffreyss-Theory-of-Probability-Revisited/10.1214/09-STS284.full).

Comment: @Dave : You can interpret the $a_i$'s as probabilities, but they are not any prior probabilities -- because, to reiterate, prior probabilities are coefficients, not of random variables (r.v.'s), but of probability distributions. A r.v. is a measurable map, whereas a probability distribution is a probability measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra. You can also think of prior probabilities as coefficients of pdf's. But again, a pdf is not a r.v.

Comment: @Dave : If the $X_i$'s are independent, then $S:=\sum_i a_iX_i$ is also normal. The Fisher information of a normal location family is the reciprocal of its variance; other kinds of information should also be decreasing as the variance increases. So, minimizing information should usually mean minimizing the variance, and the variance of $S$ is minimized if $a_i\propto1/\sigma_i^2$, as you noted.

Comment: @Dave : Oops! I should have said "maximizing information". We don't want to minimize information, but if we did, we would maximize the variance of $S$, which occurs when an $a_i$ corresponding to a largest $\sigma_i$ is $1$, and all the other $a_i$'s are $0$.